Lower Bound on the Probability for the Sum of IID Random Variables
Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be $n$ iid normalized random variables (with finite variance, possibly sub-Gaussian).
Suppose further that $\mathbb{P}(X_1 > 0 ) > 1/2$, implying a positive skew in the distribution.
I am interested in proving the following statement:

There exists $c>0$ (possibly depending on the distribution) such that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_1+\dots+X_n> c \sqrt n\right) > 1/2\quad \forall n\geq 1.
$$

Berry-Essen theorem does not seem to be helpful.
Also, Theorem 1 (b) from [1] could work but I have not managed to bound $\mathbb{P}(X_1+\dots+X_n\leq 0)<\tilde c$, for some $\tilde c <1/2$.
I have seen this question in this site, which primarily focus on upper bounds for tail probabilities, but not lower bounds.
References
[1] Bengt Rosén "On the asymptotic distribution of sums of independent identically distributed random variables," Arkiv för Matematik, Ark. Mat. 4(4), 323-332, (13 aug. 1962)

This conjecture is not true.
E.g., let $P(X_i=q)=p=1-P(X_i=-p)$, where $p\in(1/2,1)$ and $q:=1-p$, so that $P(X_i>0)>1/2$, $EX_i=0$, and $Var\,X_i=pq$ for each $i$. Then for any real $c>0$ and $S_n:=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, by the central limit theorem,
$$P(S_n>c\sqrt n)=P\Big(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{npq}}>\frac c{\sqrt{pq}}\Big)
\underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow P\Big(Z>\frac c{\sqrt{pq}}\Big)<1/2,$$
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. So, $P(S_n>c\sqrt n)<1/2$ for all large enough $n$. $\quad\Box$
